# Custom layout ListPreference

Tags: android, listpreference

Prompt please where it is possible to read about creating a custom layout listpreference ( background and layout top panel, panel button ). Met - examples only for custom row.
Sorry - google translate.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create a custom layout for a `ListPreference`. You can, however, create your own custom `DialogPreference` and set that up to look like whatever you wish.

For example, [here is a `DialogPreference` that uses a `TimePicker` to allow the user to choose a time](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/blob/master/19-Alarm/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial/TimePreference.java). [Here is a `DialogPreference` that allows the user to choose a color](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer/blob/master/colormixer/src/com/commonsware/cwac/colormixer/ColorPreference.java).

Comment: I know this is an old post, but since I am coding my customized ListPrefence now I though I might leave this comment for future coders.    **I think not being able to extend ListPreference is bad, because it defeats the object oriented approach **  To achieve what I want I am practically replicating 90% of ListPreference code. When I started coding my custom ListPreference I was hoping I could only add the 10% I needed.

Comment: @ilomambo it's more like ListPreference is being deprecated in favour of DialogPreference

Answer (score 3):

in your *preference.xml* file you can refer to your custom ListPreference by the full name of the class i.e. *com.example.MyPreference*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="pref_wifi_key"
    android:title="@string/settings">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="pref_wifi_remove"
        android:title="@string/remove_wifi"/>
    <com.example.MyPreference
    android:title="@string/add_wifi"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then your class *MyPreference* hould be something like this:

```
import android.preference.ListPreference;

public class MyPreference extends ListPreference  {

    Context context;

    public MyPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.context = context;
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.yourLayout); //inherited from DialogPreference
        setEntries(new CharSequence[] {"one", "two"});
        setEntryValues(new CharSequence[] {"item1", "item2"});
    }
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "item_selected",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. in your preference xml file

   <your.domain.CustomListPreference
   .../>
2. CustomListPreference.java

   ```
   class CustomListPreference extends ListPreference {

   mListAdapter = new your_custom_list_adapter();
   private int mClickedDialogEntryIndex;
   public CustomListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public CustomListPreference(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
         mClickedDialogEntryIndex = findIndexOfValue(getValue());
         builder.setSingleChoiceItems(mListAdapter, mClickedDialogEntryIndex,
               new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       if (mClickedDialogEntryIndex != which) {
                           mClickedDialogEntryIndex = which;
                           CustomListPreference.this.notifyChanged();
                       }
                       CustomListPreference.this.onClick(dialog, DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                       dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });
         builder.setPositiveButton(null, null);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
       CharSequence[] entryValues = getEntryValues();
       if (positiveResult && mClickedDialogEntryIndex >= 0 && entryValues != null) {
           String value = entryValues[mClickedDialogEntryIndex].toString();
           if (callChangeListener(value)) {
               setValue(value);
           }
       }
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: Pretty simple, actually. Thanks a lot.