# How to increase Preference Height using Preference Activity?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I am trying to show list of images in `Preference`, i can make it using `ListPreference` but want to show without Dialog.

I tried the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843075/1278196), but getting 
`ClassCastException`.

It should work dynamically else i can customize each preference and add it, but that would be poor.

Please see the attached sample image.

Any Help/Suggestion would be highly appreciable.

[image: Sample Image]

***Updated.***

I can create each custom `Preference` class to show images, but as i have 5 images need to be created different classes. See the Output attached image. Is there any alternate way to make it dynamically instead of static way?

[image: Output Image]

Comment: you can use your own preference class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14033099/1342413

Comment: I don't want to show in dialog as i stated in the question..

Comment: Are you creating the preference from xml? please show me the code of your static solution

Answer (score 1):

I havent tried this, but I would build everything in code then. so try to put this code in a *for()* statement in the preference class:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1);
layout.setId(567890);

PreferenceScreen preference;
preference = getPreferenceScreen();
Preference new_preference = new Preference(this);
new_preference.setKey("key1");
new_preference.setTitle("");
new_preference.setLayoutResource(567890);
preference.addPreference(new_preference);
```

Comment: How can i change image for each preference??

Comment: each preference would use diff layout. each layout would contain diff background

Comment: Isn't there any better solution to this?? How can i reference images and change on click of preference? isn't that possible?

Comment: so you want to change the bg of 1 preference by clicking on it? you havent mentioned this

Comment: If i have to create different layout for each preference, then how it works dynamically?? if this can be answered, then rest can be done..

Comment: when you create the custom layout for your custom preference use some iterator in the name of the bg image: `layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background+i);  
layout.setId(567890+i);`

Comment: Getting resource not found exception on Id